# Route calculation is not accurate while importing route from a list of points - HERE SDK for Android/iOS(Premium Edition)

Tags: here-api, heremaps-android-sdk, heremaps-ios-sdk

We're trying to use `CoreRouter.calculateRoute(List<GeoCoordinate>, RouteOptions, Listener)` method as documented [here](https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-premium/dev_guide/topics/import-route.html) to calculate a route from a list of points. The list of points is from a GPX file exported from Google map.

Please check the origin route on google map here
[origin route](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4P9Xv.jpg)
(https://www.google.com/maps/d/u/0/edit?mid=1jlwfml-kg0QLW7vHB4aMw6pDjvTevHU&usp=sharing)

The result we got in HERE MAP is like this:
[HERE Map result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BIM98.png)

We compared the route points one by one between Google Map and HERE Map, and found that the point does not sit perfectly on a road on Here map as it does on Google map. Please check the comparison here: [Comparison](https://i.stack.imgur.com/neWbP.png)

The list of points:

```xml
<trkpt lat="37.3665039" lon="-121.9179512">
        <name>TP0</name>
      </trkpt>
      <trkpt lat="37.3663126" lon="-121.9178105">
        <name>TP1</name>
      </trkpt>
      <trkpt lat="37.3660126" lon="-121.9175858">
        <name>TP2</name>
      </trkpt>
      <trkpt lat="37.3657063" lon="-121.9173579">
        <name>TP3</name>
      </trkpt>
      <trkpt lat="37.3653819" lon="-121.9171101">
        <name>TP4</name>
      </trkpt>
      <trkpt lat="37.3652228" lon="-121.916993">
        <name>TP5</name>
      </trkpt>
      <trkpt lat="37.3653404" lon="-121.9167218">
        <name>TP6</name>
      </trkpt>
      <trkpt lat="37.3657065" lon="-121.9159425">
        <name>TP7</name>
      </trkpt>
      <trkpt lat="37.3659858" lon="-121.9153481">
        <name>TP8</name>
      </trkpt>
      <trkpt lat="37.366333" lon="-121.9146232">
        <name>TP9</name>
      </trkpt>
      <trkpt lat="37.3663824" lon="-121.9145151">
        <name>TP10</name>
      </trkpt>
      <trkpt lat="37.3666919" lon="-121.9139078">
        <name>TP11</name>
      </trkpt>
      <trkpt lat="37.366698" lon="-121.9137683">
        <name>TP12</name>
      </trkpt>
      <trkpt lat="37.3666968" lon="-121.913702">
        <name>TP13</name>
      </trkpt>
      <trkpt lat="37.3666941" lon="-121.9136539">
        <name>TP14</name>
      </trkpt>
      <trkpt lat="37.3666879" lon="-121.9136134">
        <name>TP15</name>
      </trkpt>
      <trkpt lat="37.3666756" lon="-121.913573">
        <name>TP16</name>
      </trkpt>
      <trkpt lat="37.3666331" lon="-121.913451">
        <name>TP17</name>
      </trkpt>
      <trkpt lat="37.3664775" lon="-121.9133349">
        <name>TP18</name>
      </trkpt>
      <trkpt lat="37.3659049" lon="-121.9129044">
        <name>TP19</name>
      </trkpt>
      <trkpt lat="37.3658757" lon="-121.9129628">
        <name>TP20</name>
      </trkpt>
```

Is there a way to calculate the route more accurate using `CoreRouter.calculateRoute(List<GeoCoordinate>, RouteOptions, Listener)` method?

The code in our project is like below:

```
 val TESTING_WAYPOINTS = arrayOf(
            GeoCoordinate(37.3665039, -121.9179512),
            GeoCoordinate(37.3663126, -121.9178105),
            GeoCoordinate(37.3660126, -121.9175858),
            GeoCoordinate(37.3657063, -121.9173579),
            GeoCoordinate(37.3653819, -121.9171101),
            GeoCoordinate(37.3652228, -121.916993),
            GeoCoordinate(37.3653404, -121.9167218),
            GeoCoordinate(37.3657065, -121.9159425),
            GeoCoordinate(37.3659858, -121.9153481),
            GeoCoordinate(37.366333, -121.9146232),
            GeoCoordinate(37.3663824, -121.9145151),
            GeoCoordinate(37.3666919, -121.9139078),
            GeoCoordinate(37.366698, -121.9137683),
            GeoCoordinate(37.3666968, -121.913702),
            GeoCoordinate(37.3666941, -121.9136539),
            GeoCoordinate(37.3666879, -121.9136134),
            GeoCoordinate(37.3666756, -121.913573),
            GeoCoordinate(37.3666331, -121.913451),
            GeoCoordinate(37.3664775, -121.9133349),
            GeoCoordinate(37.3659049, -121.9129044),
            GeoCoordinate(37.366377, -121.9137508), 
            GeoCoordinate(37.3658757, -121.9129628),
        )

    // set route options
    val mRouteOptions = RouteOptions().apply {
        this.transportMode = RouteOptions.TransportMode.CAR
        this.routeCount = navigationOptions.routeCount
        this.routeType = navigationOptions.routeType
        setTunnelsAllowed(navigationOptions.tunnelAllowed)
        setTollRoadsAllowed(navigationOptions.tollAllowed)
        setHighwaysAllowed(navigationOptions.highwaysAllowed)
        setFerriesAllowed(navigationOptions.boatsAllowed)
        setDirtRoadsAllowed(navigationOptions.dirtRoadsAllowed)
        this.locale = Locale("en")
    })

    fun calculateRoute(listener: CoreRouter.Listener) {
        mCoreRouterListener = listener
        // force using the preset waypoints
        val presetWaypoints = TESTING_WAYPOINTS
        for (p in presetWaypoints) {
            Log.d(TAG, "[TRACK]: ${p.latitude} ${p.longitude}")
            mRoutePoints.add(p)
        }

        mCoreRouter.calculateRoute(mRoutePoints, mRouteOptions, this)
    }
```

Comment: Could you please share the code snippet. We need to check what all things are getting passed to CoreRouter.calculateRoute(List<GeoCoordinate>, RouteOptions, Listener)

Comment: @HEREDeveloperSupport, I added the code snippet in the question. Could you please take a look? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As we see lot of options are used in the request. So the router will try to find the best optimized route based on the options provided in the request. If you want to compare the requests with any other service, just use the plain requests without any restrictions  in both services.

```
// set route options
val mRouteOptions = RouteOptions().apply {
    this.transportMode = RouteOptions.TransportMode.CAR
    this.routeCount = navigationOptions.routeCount
    this.routeType = navigationOptions.routeType
    setTunnelsAllowed(navigationOptions.tunnelAllowed)
    setTollRoadsAllowed(navigationOptions.tollAllowed)
    setHighwaysAllowed(navigationOptions.highwaysAllowed)
    setFerriesAllowed(navigationOptions.boatsAllowed)
    setDirtRoadsAllowed(navigationOptions.dirtRoadsAllowed)
    this.locale = Locale("en")
})
```

Comment: If your account is being shared by multiple users at your company, please make sure they are **all** informed on how our site works. On multiple occasions, this account has submitted answers that have had improper formatting that could have easily been fixed, and others the answers have been fine.